How to declare list of values that is then used in the WHERE clauses
I have a query that declares a singular date and then uses WHERE clauses based on that date to confine to the month.
Example:
declare @date date = '8/31/2024';

select *
from x
where ReportDate = @date
  and ApprovedDate <= @date
  and ApprovedDate > eomonth(@date,-1)

The problem is I have to copy and paste the outputs into Excel, change the date, and rinse and repeat for every month in the year. What I'd like to do is be able to use one query that will give me the entire year's data in one go without fumbling around with the date over and over again.
So for example if I had this dataset that essentially only ever grows longer day by day, I'd get duplicative items (A + B) in subsequent months:



ReportDate
Item
ApprovedDate




8/31/2024
A
5/15/2024


8/31/2024
B
7/6/2024


8/31/2024
C
8/2/2024


7/31/2024
A
5/15/2024


7/31/2024
B
7/6/2024



On the first run of the query, I'd run it as above so that it would return only Item "C".



ReportDate
Item
ApprovedDate




8/31/2024
C
8/2/2024



On the second run, I'd change the date to 7/31/2024 so it would return only item "B".



ReportDate
Item
ApprovedDate




7/31/2024
B
7/6/2024



But what I'd like is to declare a set of dates (8/31/2024, 7/31/2024) and only have to the query it once to return this:



ReportDate
Item
ApprovedDate




8/31/2024
C
8/2/2024


7/31/2024
B
7/6/2024



What can I try next?

Do you actually want to declare a list? Or declare a startdate and an enddate and get results for every month within the range?

Remove the @date variable:
select *
from x
where ApprovedDate <= ReportDate
and ApprovedDate > eomonth(ReportDate, -1)
and ReportDate in ('8/31/2024', '7/31/2024')


Gah it was right in front of my eyes, so simple, thank you!

See What to do when someone answers your question

It sounds like you need two things:

The ability to select a range of ReportDate values.
Logic to limit results to those where ApprovedDate falls in the same month.

The report date range can be handled in several ways. You can define a list and filter using ReportDate IN ('2024-07-30', '2024-08-31'). You can define a range and filter using ReportDate BETWEEN '2024-07-30' AND '2024-08-31' or using variables with ReportDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ThruDate. If you want the entire year, you can filter using YEAR(ReportDate) = 2024.
For the ApprovedDate filter, I believe you can just use EOMONTH(ApprovedDate) = ReportDate.
SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE YEAR(ReportDate) = 2024
AND EOMONTH(ApprovedDate) = ReportDate

Results:



ReportDate
Item
ApprovedDate




2024-08-31
C
2024-08-02


2024-07-31
B
2024-07-06



Fiddle.

Thank you so much for the multiple ways to attack this!

If your goal is to target specific dates, you could create a temporary table to hold the dates you wish to use, and join it to the main table. Please see Option A.
If your goal is to target a specific range, you could use the BETWEEN function for your filter criteria or DATEADD() with GETDATE().
Option A

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DateSet') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DateSet;

CREATE TABLE #DateSet (SelectedDate DATE);

INSERT INTO #DateSet (SelectedDate)
VALUES ('2024-08-31'), ('2024-07-31');


SELECT DISTINCT x.ReportDate, x.Item, x.ApprovedDate
FROM x
JOIN #DateSet AS d ON x.ReportDate = d.SelectedDate
WHERE x.ApprovedDate <= d.SelectedDate
  AND x.ApprovedDate > EOMONTH(d.SelectedDate, -1);

DROP TABLE #DateSet;



Using a CTE to pull in the distinct report dates:
;with _reports as
(
    select  distinct
            reportdate
    from    x
)

select  *
from    x   a
where   exists(select * from _reports b where b.reportdate = a.reportdate and b.reportdate = EOMONTH(a.approveddate))

